# Which spatial Data structure to use when Coordinates of the features is updating frequently? I have tried R tree, 2d Grid

Tags: multidimensional-array, gis, spatial-index, r-tree

I have N numbers of geographical points and coordinates of the points are being updated frequently. And the number N is very big.
I need to find points within a rectangle.
I have tried searching by all points, by using 2d Array grid and R tree.
I had to remove and then insert again which is costly operation.

Comment: quad tree? GIST?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing spatial data is a complex topic. If you just have points you can index them using a sparse grid (better memory utilization than just 2d array):

```
class SpatialGrid:

    def __init__(self, cell_size):
        self._cells: DefaultDict[Tuple, Set] = defaultdict(set)
        self._cell_size = cell_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cells)

    def _key(self, x: float, y: float) -> Tuple:
        return int(x / self._cell_size), int(y / self._cell_size)

    def add(self, x: float, y: float, obj: object) -> None:
        i_x, i_y = self._key(x, y)
        for i in (-1, 0, 1):
            for j in (-1, 0, 1):
                self._cells[(i_x + i, i_y + j)].add(obj)

    def get(self, x: float, y: float) -> Set:
        return self._cells[self._key(x, y)]

    def contains(self, x: float, y: float) -> bool:
        return self._key(x, y) in self._cells
```

if you need to find by rectangle then you can just iterate over grid cells that are in that rectangle

But of course you will need to remove and insert points whenever the coordinates change. Indexing is costly.

Comment: clarification: for the get() and contains() methods you can put coordinate of the cell, that's how you can find things within a rectangle - you just need to check all cells in that rectangle

Comment: I have already done that. I need to  periodically update coordinate positions.